# Qt5VSAddin for Visual Studio 2013 - where are the Settings saved to? And/or how to disable addin?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2013

I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 professional and Qt 5, so I installed Qt5VSAddin, which is working as intended (I can choose an installed Qt version; meta compiling etc is working; Creating new VS Qt project works like a charm).

However I would like to use the same project and solution files on different machines, where Qt isn't necessarily installed in the same directory.

At the moment, the Qt addin changes the content of the project's `.vcxproj.user` file and adds the line `<QTDIR>directorypath</QTDIR>` with "directorypath" being the path I've chosen in QT5->"Qt options"->"Qt versions" of the addin. So if I compile on that machine, QTDIR in the .user is changed to that machine's Qt installation directory, meaning that I'll destroy the project file for anyone else trying to compile the project on another machine (maybe someone without the addin).

What I want to do is to change this Qt version information to a path relative to an environmental variable, like `<QTDIR>$(MY_QTDIR)</QTDIR>` or `<QTDIR>$(MY_DEV_ENVIRONMENT)/Qt/</QTDIR>`. Unfortunately, Qt5VSAddin does not allow to create QT versions with environmental variables (at least not with $() syntax) because it does not let you click on the "OK" button in this case.
I tried to change it in the `.vcxproj.user` file direcly, which does work (I can compile the project this way on another machine without the addin), but on VS2013 restart or clean->build it will overwrite the changes again.

I tried to deactivate the Qt5VSAddin in extras->add-in-manager (unchecked all 3 boxes) but after VS restart, the addin is active again. How can I deactivate it completely without uninstalling (I would still like to create new Qt projects with the addin occasionally)

Is there a way to set the Qt version path of the Qt5VSAddin including an environmental variable? 
If not from the GUI, maybe I can change it directly in some config file? unfortunately I couldn't find the file/location where the addin configuration parameters are placed. So where are those pathes and settings saved to?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addin stores its settings and Qt paths in registry: `HKCU\Software\Digia\Qt5VS2013\` and `HKCU\Software\Digia\Versions\` accordingly.

Comment: thank you, this is the place where I can change the pathes manually, but the Addin won't accept a manually edited path with an environmental variable added :-( so I'll continue the "just disable the addin" way...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find yet where those settings are placed.
I tried to create a fantasy-named-folder and search for that foldername within all files on my drive, but didn't find it...

However I found the reason why I could not deactivate the Qt5 addin in Visual Studio for longer than the current session:

- Visual Studio has to be started as `Administrator` to change the Addin options (at least for the Qt5 Addin) persistently!

After deactivating the addin, everything works as I like it.

I'm still interested in finding and manipulating the Qt-Versions pathes of the addin, since accessing the `new project->Qt5 Projects` templates, without re-activating the addin, results in a broken/incomplete project. So to get a working new Qt project, atm I have to restart VS as admin, activate the addin and create the project there (followed by manually editing ther `.user` file and deactivating the addin as admin again)...

**UPDATE:** Unchecking only the "start" addin option as an admin, I can activate the addin for non-admins on-the-fly to create a new project. I think I will be able to work this way, however I'm still interested in the second question.